# Catching exceptions when calling set in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I haven't touch JS or Firebase for a while so forgive style issues. I ran into an issue calling [`set`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#set) on a `DocumentReference`. You can't have a value of `undefined`. That's fine, but i expected my catch block to catch the exception, but instead the whole function crashed (this is within a cloud function). I've tried to simplify the code:

```js
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {    
    return db.collection('users').doc('someid').set({
        first: undefined
    })
    .then(()=> {
        res.send('it worked?');
    })
    .catch((error: any) => {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('it didn\'t work');
    })
})
```

A couple of notes, I'm using ExpressJS and testing this in the Firebase Functions emulator, writing to the real Firestore.

So my question is why isn't the error being caught? Instead I receive a response containing the exception details. Is the solution to check values before calling set? And if so, given it isn't written in the documentation linked above, how are you meant to know that?

Comment: I don't know why the function is crashing.  It might be a bug in the emulator, which you should log [here on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).  As for undefined input, undefined is almost never a valid input to an API.  Undefined inputs are more likely to be due to a bug than an intentional value.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `set()` function is throwing the exception before returning a promise because the parameter is invalid so you should validate that your object has no undefined fields.

From experimentation I have found that it accepts `null`s so here is a way to work around the issue:

```
let firstValue;

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {    
    return db.collection('users').doc('someid').set({
        first: firstValue || null
    })
    .then(()=> {
        res.send('it worked?');
    })
    .catch((error: any) => {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('it didn\'t work');
    })
})
```

I haven't found any indication in the documentation that the `set()` function does not accept data with `undefined` fields but I don't know why you would get them there in the first place as I don't think it would be useful to store it in the database. Also it is a best practice to always initialize variables to avoid having to deal with such issues, use blank values such as `""` or `{}` if you haven't calculated the value yet.